# Changing the color of a customized icon component upon hovering

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

Using Angular, I have created an icon component, which allows for attributes `size` and `color` to be set. The following HTML tag creates an icon:

```
<my-icon size='medium' color='primary-dark'>person</my-icon>
```

This component is essentially just a wrapper of the material-icons tag. The attributes `size` and `color` simply add a CSS class to the material-icons tag.

Now, I am using this icon component in one of my parent components. When hovering above this icon, I want to change its color. For this purpose, I have just created some SCSS in my parent component:

```
my-icon {
  &:hover {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

I have also tried adding an `::ng-deep` in front of `my-icon`. However, the color doesn't change upon hovering above the icon. Changing the opacity instead of the color works.

Apparently, my parent cannot change the color of my icon. I am not sure why. Taking a look at the browser console simply shows that the icon component has a CSS class connected to it, which represents the color set by the color attribute.

Anyways: Can somebody explain this behavior to me?

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS syntax is not valid: https://codebeautify.org/cssvalidate/y22780750

Correct syntax:

styles.css

```css
my-icon > mat-icon:hover {
  color: blue;
}

.green {
  color: green;
}

.medium {
  font-size: 50px !important;
}

.large {
  font-size: 100px !important;
}
```

Do note, that for size `font-size` I needed to use `!important` to overwrite material defaults.

> If you use the !important rule, it will override ALL previous styling rules for that specific property on that element! https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp

Parent html:

```html
<my-icon [size]="'medium'" [color]="'green'" [name]="'person'"></my-icon>
```

For `@Input` binding we use brackets `[]` though it will work without too, just will be more understandable that its a binding. Probably will avoid some unnecessary warnings too from TS or linters.

MyIconComponent:

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-icon',
  template: `<mat-icon [ngClass]="[size, color]" aria-label="Example home icon">{{name}}</mat-icon>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`],
})
export class MyIconComponent {
  @Input() size: string;
  @Input() color: string;
  @Input() name: string;
}
```

So when you are saying `my-icon:hover { color: blue;}` *(<- this one is valid syntax)* it means `my-icon` should be blue on hover. Ok fine. But the the children of `my-icon`, the `mat-icon`'s, are still going to be green. `my-icon` won't care if it's color should be blue, what should be blue exactly, it doesn't know on what the color should be applied on.

However if you did for example `my-icon :hover { background: blue !important; }` then something would happen with `my-icon` because it does have a background (you can try this with the demo).

Using `my-icon > mat-icon` we target children of `my-icon` and only `mat-icon`'s and their color will be blue on `:hover`, since `mat-icons` know what to do with property `color` - so, they will change their color on hover.

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bqwdqu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

You can apply hover style from css to that class
For more reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).